# IOS Twitter Digits - Change Title, Placeholders

Tags: ios, authentication, sms, phone-number, twitter-digits

I am trying to implement Twitter Digits for sms login in my ios demo.

It is all working. But, I want to change "What is your number", "Send confirmation code", and user agreement text below because it does not automatically change those values into my language.

[image: Screenshot]

I can also create my own UI if there is a way to call "Send confirmation code" button.

Is there any change doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution. I have forcefully set my app language into my language. Digits already supports my language. It is all done at once.

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["lang_Code"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Thank me.